# Magento2 - use layouts like bootstrap

Tags: magento2, cms, rwd

looking for a way to use a grid layout for CMS pages (such as home page) of magento2 - theme copied from Luma into a custom.

would like to have the ability to set up two divs to float side by side, like you can do with bootstrap such as this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

but without creating custom classes for it? (I tried adding bootstrap, but it comflicts with whatever Magento is using for Luma's responsiveness) - so I figured, maybe they have some classes I can tie into?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to go to bootstrap website and customize bootstrap before downloading.

When you are on the page disable all options but "Grid system" after that scroll all the way down to download the zip file.

In the zip file you will find bootstrap.css file, you can add it straight away because it won't conflict with Magento 2 own css.

Comment: Thank you so much! that's exactly what I needed, I didn't know I could do that!